# Calculate world-up vector of object on arbitrary axis (ThreeJS)

Tags: javascript, three.js, calculus

I'm having trouble of finding the absolute rotation of my object on an arbitrary axis.

So far I've been able to get the relative rotation of my object. To get the relative rotation, I've placed a plane behind the object that's facing the selected axis. By raycasting on this plane I'm able to retrieve the 3D coordinates to calculate the angle by using `atan2`.

The code to get relative rotation of my object:

```
let planeCrossObjectDir = planeNormal.clone().cross(this.objectUpDirection).normalize();
let projectedPoint = new THREE.Vector3();
rayPlane.projectPoint(intersection.point, projectedPoint);
let centerProjected = new THREE.Vector3();
rayPlane.projectPoint(this.raycastPlane.position, centerProjected);

let u1 = this.objectUpDirection.dot(projectedPoint);
let v1 = planeCrossObjectDir.dot(projectedPoint);
let u2 =  this.objectUpDirection.dot(centerProjected);
let dotv2 = planeCrossObjectDir.dot(centerProjected);

let uvCoord = new THREE.Vector2(u1, v1).sub(new THREE.Vector2(u2, dotv2));

var theta = Math.atan2(uvCoord.y, uvCoord.x); // range [-PI, PI]
theta *= 180 / Math.PI; // range [-180, 180]
if (theta < 0) theta = 360 + theta; // range [0, 360]
let objectsRotation = Math.round(360 - theta); // invert rotation
```

I want to do the same principle for calculating the absolute rotation by changing the `planeCrossObjectDir` and using the world UP-vector of the plane instead of `this.objectUpDirection`.

The problem however is: I don't know how to calculate this..

I've made a drawing to simplify things/clarification:
[image: World Up-vector of plane]

Answer (score 2):

I think you're taking the long way around. Your object's `matrixWorld` property should contain the finalized world values, including position, rotation, and scale. You can get the rotation component two different ways:

**As a matrix:**

```
var rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().extractRotation(yourObject.matrixWorld);
// rotationMatrix will now contains the rotation component of your object's world matrix
```

**As a Quaternion:**

```
var position = new THREE.Vector3();
var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
var scale = new THREE.Vector3();
yourObject.matrixWorld.decompose(position, quaternion, scale);
// quaternion now contains your object's world rotation as a quaternion
```

**Apply to the up-vector:**

You can then update an up-vector based on which method you used:

```
var up1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0).applyMatrix4(rotationMatrix).normalize();
```

Or

```
var up2 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0).applyQuaternion(quaternion).normalize();
```

If you try both paths, you'll see that they arrive at the same result (within reason for JavaScript).

If you have questions, or if I misunderstood your question, leave a comment.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem (probably my fault because it's hard to explain ;P). Your answer gives me the worlds up-vector of the object. At start this seems correct, but if I rotate the object downwards (Y: 180 degrees), the up-vector will also be pointing downwards. You could say that the answer is just simply taking the worlds up-vector (`THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0)`), but i want the X & Z to be applied as well (with Y facing to the worlds up-vector). This depends of course on which axis you're rotating.